# Add all models to admin site django 1.9

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I need to add my model to my admin site on django 1.9, 
I was using this code earlier:

```
for model in get_model(get_app('campaign')):
     admin.site.register(model)
```

However, it isn't supported by django 1.9 verison. Is there a new way to do this?

Comment: What is `get_model`? What error do you get in Django 1.9? If you add this information to your question, it will be more useful to other users that are upgrading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`get_models()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models) method of the app config.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.apps import apps

myapp = apps.get_app_config('myapp')
for model in myapp.get_models():
    admin.site.register(model)
```

In modern versions of Django (I'm not sure whether it will work for Django < 1.10), you can simplify this to:

```
myapp = apps.get_app_config('myapp')
admin.site.register(myapp.get_models())
```

Comment: since it takes an iterable it could be:`admin.site.register([model for model in my app.get_models()])`

Comment: @timj98 in that case you don't need the list comprehension, you could do `admin.site.register(myapp.get_models())`.